# Digital Ocean Apps can't locate chromium directory for puppeteer

Tags: node.js, command-line, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I've been wrestling with this all day. I get the below error whenever I try to run my puppeteer script on Digital Ocean Apps.

`/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-818858/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I did some research and found this helpful link below that seems to be the accepted solution.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5661

However since I'm using digital ocean apps instead of the standard digital ocean droplets it seems I can't use sudo commands in the command line so I can't actually run these in the command line.

Does anyone know of anyway around this?

I'm using node.js by the way.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: I'd suggest thatyou just contact their support for this.

Comment: I will, but I need a more immediate solution. This is for a work project and it has deadlines and such. I tried downloading the chromium binary directly and using executablePath to point to it, same thing though. Works locally but I get the same exact error when I push it up.

Comment: Digital Ocean support just got back to me and recommended I use a docker file as shown in the link below to solve this. I've never worked with Dockerfiles before and have no idea how they work. Can someone help shed some light on this?

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker

Comment: You'll need to save the Dockerfile sample to a file `Dockerfile` and run the rest of the commands in the same directory.

Comment: The below repo is an example they gave me. They’ve been very helpful. Would I just set it up exactly how they have it here and replace the integrated tests file with my own index.js? 

https://github.com/buildkite/docker-puppeteer

Comment: I guess step one would be to try their repo and their code and make sure it works. Then you can start trying to introduce your scripts (sorry, can't be more helpful, again - didn't use their apps).

Comment: Hi! Thanks again for your assistance. I have the dockerfile built and it's running on github without errors, however digital ocean apps isn't even picking up on the dockerfile? I have a couple general questions.

1. If it builds in github does it even need to rebuild in the digital ocean apps?
2. The below example illustrates additional steps that need to be taken, the problem is I'm not sure where these go or how to execute them. The documentation isn't very clear

Comment: Build the container:
```docker build -t puppeteer-chrome-linux .```
Run the container by passing node -e "<yourscript.js content as a string>" as the command:

```docker run -i --init --rm --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN \
   --name puppeteer-chrome puppeteer-chrome-linux \
   node -e "`cat yourscript.js`"```

Comment: I suppose you run these command in D.O. console somewhere. It's a paid service, so why not ask their support about how to use it?

Answer (score 3):

The post by David Avikasis is the **solution** for using puppeteer with DigitalOcean's App Platform. I want to expand on his answer by explaining how I got puppeteer to work. Firstly, I would like to note that DigitalOcean App Platform does **not** support puppeteer **"without"** using a Dockerfile (or at least not in March 2023).

Here is the `Dockerfile` for building a deploying my Node.js app:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine AS final

# --- START ---

RUN apk add --no-cache chromium ca-certificates
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser

# --- END ---

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/.env.example .
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

The code between `--- START ---` and `--- END ---` is specific to installing puppeteer. The rest of the docker file can be ignored if you already have your own configuration.

Here is the Node.js code used to launch puppeteer:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: process.env.PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH,
  args: ['--no-sandbox'], // required
})
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this issue myself. I needed a way to run puppeteer in order to run Scully (static site generator for Angular) during my build process.
My solution was to use a Dockerfile to build my DigitalOcean App Platform's app. You can ignore the Scully stuff if not needed (Putting it here for others who struggles with this use case like me) and have a regular `yarn build:prod` or such, and use something like `dist/myapp` (instead of `dist/scully`) as output_dir in the appspec.

In your app's root folder, you should have these files:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:14-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
      chromium \
      ca-certificates

# This is to prevent the build from getting stuck on "Taking snapshot of full filesystem"
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true 

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .

# Needed because we set PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV SCULLY_PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser

# build_prod_scully is set in package.json to: "ng build --configuration=production && yarn scully --scanRoutes"
RUN yarn build_prod_scully
```

`digitalocean.appspec.yml`

```yaml
domains:
  - domain: myapp.com
    type: PRIMARY
  - domain: www.myapp.com
    type: ALIAS
name: myapp
region: fra
static_sites:
  - catchall_document: index.html
    github:
      branch: master
      deploy_on_push: true
      repo: myname/myapp
    name: myapp
    output_dir: /usr/src/myapp/dist/scully # <--- /user/src/myapp refering to the Dockerfile's WORKDIR, dist/scully refers to scully config file's `outDir`
    routes:
      - path: /
    source_dir: /
    dockerfile_path: Dockerfile # <-- may be unneeded unless you already have an app set up.
```

Then upload the `digitalocean.appspec.yml` from your computer to your
App Dasboard > Settings > App > AppSpec > edit > Upload File.

For those who use it with Scully, I've also used the following inside scully.config.ts

```
export const config: ScullyConfig = {
...
puppeteerLaunchOptions: {
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid--sandbox'],
  },
};
```

Hope it helps.